# declare value from file with file get contents

Tags: php, arduino, gauge

I'm trying to modify it arduino code, temperature gauge to PHP, and have problem with declare value from file with  file_get_contents

Here is original code :

[link](https://startingelectronics.org/projects/arduino-projects/web-server-two-temperature-gauges/)

And here is my modify code:

I change only in section after: --- Gauge Code Ends --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arduino Two Temperaturesa</title>
        <script>

        var data_val = 0

        var data_val2 = 0;
<!-- Gauge Code Starts -->
var Gauge=function(b){function l(a,b){for(var c in b)"object"==typeof b[c]&&"[object Array]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(b[c])&&"renderTo"!=c?("object"!=typeof a[c]&&(a[c]={}),l(a[c],b[c])):a[c]=b[c]}function q(){z.width=b.width;z.height=b.height;A=z.cloneNode(!0);B=A.getContext("2d");C=z.width;D=z.height;t=C/2;u=D/2;f=t<u?t:u;A.i8d=!1;B.translate(t,u);B.save();a.translate(t,u);a.save()}function v(a){var b=new Date;G=setInterval(function(){var c=(new Date-b)/a.duration;1<c&&(c=1);var f=("function"==
typeof a.delta?a.delta:M[a.delta])(c);a.step(f);1==c&&clearInterval(G)},a.delay||10)}function k(){G&&clearInterval(G);var a=I-n,h=n,c=b.animation;v({delay:c.delay,duration:c.duration,delta:c.fn,step:function(b){n=parseFloat(h)+a*b;E.draw()}})}function e(a){return a*Math.PI/180}function g(b,h,c){c=a.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,c);c.addColorStop(0,b);c.addColorStop(1,h);return c}function p(){var m=93*(f/100),h=f-m,c=91*(f/100),e=88*(f/100),d=85*(f/100);a.save();b.glow&&(a.shadowBlur=h,a.shadowColor=
"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");a.beginPath();a.arc(0,0,m,0,2*Math.PI,!0);a.fillStyle=g("#ddd","#aaa",m);a.fill();a.restore();a.beginPath();a.arc(0,0,c,0,2*Math.PI,!0);a.fillStyle=g("#fafafa","#ccc",c);a.fill();a.beginPath();a.arc(0,0,e,0,2*Math.PI,!0);a.fillStyle=g("#eee","#f0f0f0",e);a.fill();a.beginPath();a.arc(0,0,d,0,2*Math.PI,!0);a.fillStyle=b.colors.plate;a.fill();a.save()}function w(a){var h=!1;a=0===b.majorTicksFormat.dec?Math.round(a).toString():a.toFixed(b.majorTicksFormat.dec);return 1<b.majorTicksFormat["int"]?
(h=-1<a.indexOf("."),-1<a.indexOf("-")?"-"+(b.majorTicksFormat["int"]+b.majorTicksFormat.dec+2+(h?1:0)-a.length)+a.replace("-",""):""+(b.majorTicksFormat["int"]+b.majorTicksFormat.dec+1+(h?1:0)-a.length)+a):a}function d(){var m=81*(f/100);a.lineWidth=2;a.strokeStyle=b.colors.majorTicks;a.save();if(0===b.majorTicks.length){for(var h=(b.maxValue-b.minValue)/5,c=0;5>c;c++)b.majorTicks.push(w(b.minValue+h*c));b.majorTicks.push(w(b.maxValue))}for(c=0;c<b.majorTicks.length;++c)a.rotate(e(45+c*(270/(b.majorTicks.length-
1)))),a.beginPath(),a.moveTo(0,m),a.lineTo(0,m-15*(f/100)),a.stroke(),a.restore(),a.save();b.strokeTicks&&(a.rotate(e(90)),a.beginPath(),a.arc(0,0,m,e(45),e(315),!1),a.stroke(),a.restore(),a.save())}function J(){var m=81*(f/100);a.lineWidth=1;a.strokeStyle=b.colors.minorTicks;a.save();for(var h=b.minorTicks*(b.majorTicks.length-1),c=0;c<h;++c)a.rotate(e(45+c*(270/h))),a.beginPath(),a.moveTo(0,m),a.lineTo(0,m-7.5*(f/100)),a.stroke(),a.restore(),a.save()}function s(){for(var m=55*(f/100),h=0;h<b.majorTicks.length;++h){var c=
F(m,e(45+h*(270/(b.majorTicks.length-1))));a.font=20*(f/200)+"px Arial";a.fillStyle=b.colors.numbers;a.lineWidth=0;a.textAlign="center";a.fillText(b.majorTicks[h],c.x,c.y+3)}}function x(a){var h=b.valueFormat.dec,c=b.valueFormat["int"];a=parseFloat(a);var f=0>a;a=Math.abs(a);if(0<h){a=a.toFixed(h).toString().split(".");h=0;for(c-=a[0].length;h<c;++h)a[0]="0"+a[0];a=(f?"-":"")+a[0]+"."+a[1]}else{a=Math.round(a).toString();h=0;for(c-=a.length;h<c;++h)a="0"+a;a=(f?"-":"")+a}return a}function F(a,b){var c=
Math.sin(b),f=Math.cos(b);return{x:0*f-a*c,y:0*c+a*f}}function N(){a.save();for(var m=81*(f/100),h=m-15*(f/100),c=0,g=b.highlights.length;c<g;c++){var d=b.highlights[c],r=(b.maxValue-b.minValue)/270,k=e(45+(d.from-b.minValue)/r),r=e(45+(d.to-b.minValue)/r);a.beginPath();a.rotate(e(90));a.arc(0,0,m,k,r,!1);a.restore();a.save();var l=F(h,k),p=F(m,k);a.moveTo(l.x,l.y);a.lineTo(p.x,p.y);var p=F(m,r),n=F(h,r);a.lineTo(p.x,p.y);a.lineTo(n.x,n.y);a.lineTo(l.x,l.y);a.closePath();a.fillStyle=d.color;a.fill();
a.beginPath();a.rotate(e(90));a.arc(0,0,h,k-0.2,r+0.2,!1);a.restore();a.closePath();a.fillStyle=b.colors.plate;a.fill();a.save()}}function K(){var m=12*(f/100),h=8*(f/100),c=77*(f/100),d=20*(f/100),k=4*(f/100),r=2*(f/100),l=function(){a.shadowOffsetX=2;a.shadowOffsetY=2;a.shadowBlur=10;a.shadowColor="rgba(188, 143, 143, 0.45)"};l();a.save();n=0>n?Math.abs(b.minValue-n):0<b.minValue?n-b.minValue:Math.abs(b.minValue)+n;a.rotate(e(45+n/((b.maxValue-b.minValue)/270)));a.beginPath();a.moveTo(-r,-d);a.lineTo(-k,
0);a.lineTo(-1,c);a.lineTo(1,c);a.lineTo(k,0);a.lineTo(r,-d);a.closePath();a.fillStyle=g(b.colors.needle.start,b.colors.needle.end,c-d);a.fill();a.beginPath();a.lineTo(-0.5,c);a.lineTo(-1,c);a.lineTo(-k,0);a.lineTo(-r,-d);a.lineTo(r/2-2,-d);a.closePath();a.fillStyle="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)";a.fill();a.restore();l();a.beginPath();a.arc(0,0,m,0,2*Math.PI,!0);a.fillStyle=g("#f0f0f0","#ccc",m);a.fill();a.restore();a.beginPath();a.arc(0,0,h,0,2*Math.PI,!0);a.fillStyle=g("#e8e8e8","#f5f5f5",h);a.fill()}
function L(){a.save();a.font=40*(f/200)+"px Led";var b=x(y),h=a.measureText("-"+x(0)).width,c=f-33*(f/100),g=0.12*f;a.save();var d=-h/2-0.025*f,e=c-g-0.04*f,h=h+0.05*f,g=g+0.07*f,k=0.025*f;a.beginPath();a.moveTo(d+k,e);a.lineTo(d+h-k,e);a.quadraticCurveTo(d+h,e,d+h,e+k);a.lineTo(d+h,e+g-k);a.quadraticCurveTo(d+h,e+g,d+h-k,e+g);a.lineTo(d+k,e+g);a.quadraticCurveTo(d,e+g,d,e+g-k);a.lineTo(d,e+k);a.quadraticCurveTo(d,e,d+k,e);a.closePath();d=a.createRadialGradient(0,c-0.12*f-0.025*f+(0.12*f+0.045*f)/
2,f/10,0,c-0.12*f-0.025*f+(0.12*f+0.045*f)/2,f/5);d.addColorStop(0,"#888");d.addColorStop(1,"#666");a.strokeStyle=d;a.lineWidth=0.05*f;a.stroke();a.shadowBlur=0.012*f;a.shadowColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";a.fillStyle="#babab2";a.fill();a.restore();a.shadowOffsetX=0.004*f;a.shadowOffsetY=0.004*f;a.shadowBlur=0.012*f;a.shadowColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";a.fillStyle="#444";a.textAlign="center";a.fillText(b,-0,c);a.restore()}Gauge.Collection.push(this);this.config={renderTo:null,width:200,height:200,title:!1,
maxValue:100,minValue:0,majorTicks:[],minorTicks:10,strokeTicks:!0,units:!1,valueFormat:{"int":3,dec:2},majorTicksFormat:{"int":1,dec:0},glow:!0,animation:{delay:10,duration:250,fn:"cycle"},colors:{plate:"#fff",majorTicks:"#444",minorTicks:"#666",title:"#888",units:"#888",numbers:"#444",needle:{start:"rgba(240, 128, 128, 1)",end:"rgba(255, 160, 122, .9)"}},highlights:[{from:20,to:60,color:"#eee"},{from:60,to:80,color:"#ccc"},{from:80,to:100,color:"#999"}]};var y=0,E=this,n=0,I=0,H=!1;this.setValue=
function(a){n=b.animation?y:a;var d=(b.maxValue-b.minValue)/100;I=a>b.maxValue?b.maxValue+d:a<b.minValue?b.minValue-d:a;y=a;b.animation?k():this.draw();return this};this.setRawValue=function(a){n=y=a;this.draw();return this};this.clear=function(){y=n=I=this.config.minValue;this.draw();return this};this.getValue=function(){return y};this.onready=function(){};l(this.config,b);this.config.minValue=parseFloat(this.config.minValue);this.config.maxValue=parseFloat(this.config.maxValue);b=this.config;n=
y=b.minValue;if(!b.renderTo)throw Error("Canvas element was not specified when creating the Gauge object!");var z=b.renderTo.tagName?b.renderTo:document.getElementById(b.renderTo),a=z.getContext("2d"),A,C,D,t,u,f,B;q();this.updateConfig=function(a){l(this.config,a);q();this.draw();return this};var M={linear:function(a){return a},quad:function(a){return Math.pow(a,2)},quint:function(a){return Math.pow(a,5)},cycle:function(a){return 1-Math.sin(Math.acos(a))},bounce:function(a){a:{a=1-a;for(var b=0,
c=1;;b+=c,c/=2)if(a>=(7-4*b)/11){a=-Math.pow((11-6*b-11*a)/4,2)+Math.pow(c,2);break a}a=void 0}return 1-a},elastic:function(a){a=1-a;return 1-Math.pow(2,10*(a-1))*Math.cos(30*Math.PI/3*a)}},G=null;a.lineCap="round";this.draw=function(){if(!A.i8d){B.clearRect(-t,-u,C,D);B.save();var g={ctx:a};a=B;p();N();J();d();s();b.title&&(a.save(),a.font=24*(f/200)+"px Arial",a.fillStyle=b.colors.title,a.textAlign="center",a.fillText(b.title,0,-f/4.25),a.restore());b.units&&(a.save(),a.font=22*(f/200)+"px Arial",
a.fillStyle=b.colors.units,a.textAlign="center",a.fillText(b.units,0,f/3.25),a.restore());A.i8d=!0;a=g.ctx;delete g.ctx}a.clearRect(-t,-u,C,D);a.save();a.drawImage(A,-t,-u,C,D);if(Gauge.initialized)L(),K(),H||(E.onready&&E.onready(),H=!0);else var e=setInterval(function(){Gauge.initialized&&(clearInterval(e),L(),K(),H||(E.onready&&E.onready(),H=!0))},10);return this}};Gauge.initialized=!1;
(function(){var b=document,l=b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],q=-1!=navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf("msie"),v="@font-face {font-family: 'Led';src: url('fonts/digital-7-mono."+(q?"eot":"ttf")+"');}",k=b.createElement("style");k.type="text/css";if(q)l.appendChild(k),l=k.styleSheet,l.cssText=v;else{try{k.appendChild(b.createTextNode(v))}catch(e){k.cssText=v}l.appendChild(k);l=k.styleSheet?k.styleSheet:k.sheet||b.styleSheets[b.styleSheets.length-1]}var g=setInterval(function(){if(b.body){clearInterval(g);
var e=b.createElement("div");e.style.fontFamily="Led";e.style.position="absolute";e.style.height=e.style.width=0;e.style.overflow="hidden";e.innerHTML=".";b.body.appendChild(e);setTimeout(function(){Gauge.initialized=!0;e.parentNode.removeChild(e)},250)}},1)})();Gauge.Collection=[];
Gauge.Collection.get=function(b){if("string"==typeof b)for(var l=0,q=this.length;l<q;l++){if((this[l].config.renderTo.tagName?this[l].config.renderTo:document.getElementById(this[l].config.renderTo)).getAttribute("id")==b)return this[l]}else return"number"==typeof b?this[b]:null};function domReady(b){window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",b,!1):window.attachEvent("onload",b)}
domReady(function(){function b(b){for(var e=b[0],d=1,g=b.length;d<g;d++)e+=b[d].substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+b[d].substr(1,b[d].length-1);return e}for(var l=document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"),q=0,v=l.length;q<v;q++)if("canv-gauge"==l[q].getAttribute("data-type")){var k=l[q],e={},g,p=parseInt(k.getAttribute("width"),10),w=parseInt(k.getAttribute("height"),10);e.renderTo=k;p&&(e.width=p);w&&(e.height=w);p=0;for(w=k.attributes.length;p<w;p++)if(g=k.attributes.item(p).nodeName,"data-type"!=g&&"data-"==
g.substr(0,5)){var d=g.substr(5,g.length-5).toLowerCase().split("-");if(g=k.getAttribute(g))switch(d[0]){case "colors":d[1]&&(e.colors||(e.colors={}),"needle"==d[1]?(d=g.split(/\s+/),e.colors.needle=d[0]&&d[1]?{start:d[0],end:d[1]}:g):(d.shift(),e.colors[b(d)]=g));break;case "highlights":e.highlights||(e.highlights=[]);g=g.match(/(?:(?:-?\d*\.)?(-?\d+){1,2} ){2}(?:(?:#|0x)?(?:[0-9A-F|a-f]){3,8}|rgba?\(.*?\))/g);for(var d=0,J=g.length;d<J;d++){var s=g[d].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s+/),x={};
s[0]&&""!=s[0]&&(x.from=s[0]);s[1]&&""!=s[1]&&(x.to=s[1]);s[2]&&""!=s[2]&&(x.color=s[2]);e.highlights.push(x)}break;case "animation":d[1]&&(e.animation||(e.animation={}),"fn"==d[1]&&/^\s*function\s*\(/.test(g)&&(g=eval("("+g+")")),e.animation[d[1]]=g);break;default:d=b(d);if("onready"==d)continue;if("majorTicks"==d)g=g.split(/\s+/);else if("strokeTicks"==d||"glow"==d)g="true"==g?!0:!1;else if("valueFormat"==d)if(g=g.split("."),2==g.length)g={"int":parseInt(g[0],10),dec:parseInt(g[1],10)};else continue;
e[d]=g}}e=new Gauge(e);k.getAttribute("data-value")&&e.setRawValue(parseFloat(k.getAttribute("data-value")));k.getAttribute("data-onready")&&(e.onready=function(){eval(this.config.renderTo.getAttribute("data-onready"))});e.draw()}});window.Gauge=Gauge;
<!-- Gauge Code Ends -->


<?php
$ht4 = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/ht41.txt");
?>
data_val = $ht4
data_val2 = 30 


    </script>
        <h1>Arduino Two Temperatures</h1>
        <canvas id="an_gauge_1" data-title="Inside" data-units="Temp. &deg;C" width="500" height="500" data-major-ticks="-40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150" data-type="canv-gauge" data-min-value="-40" data-max-value="150" data-highlights="-40 0 #4D89F2, 0 10 #25B8D9, 10 30 #0BB950, 30 40 #cc5, 40 150 #f33" data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('an_gauge_1').setValue(data_val);}, 200);"></canvas>
        <canvas id="an_gauge_2" data-title="Outside" data-units="Temp. &deg;C" width="500" height="500" data-major-ticks="-40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150" data-type="canv-gauge" data-min-value="-40" data-max-value="150" data-highlights="-40 0 #4D89F2, 0 10 #25B8D9, 10 30 #0BB950, 30 40 #cc5, 40 150 #f33" data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('an_gauge_2').setValue(data_val2);}, 200);"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have problem with  declare data_val and data_val2

If i write in script fixed value:

```
.
.
<!-- Gauge Code Ends -->

data_val = 20.5
data_val2 = 30.8 


    </script>
.
.
```

work temperature gauge OK,

But I want to read the temperature value for data_val from file, but not work.
I try with this:

```
<!-- Gauge Code Ends -->


<?php
$ht4 = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/ht41.txt");
?>
data_val = $ht4
data_val2 = 30.8 


    </script>
```

Fajl ht41.txt have only numbers: "23.548"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix javascript and php like that: PHP runs on the server and by the time the javascript gets executed, there will be no php and your assignment in php leads to nothing.

Instead of:

```
<?php
// This does not do anything unless you use $ht4 after this in PHP
$ht4 = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/ht41.txt");
?>
// in your javascript, there is no $ht4 variable.
data_val = $ht4
data_val2 = 30.8
```

You need something like:

```
data_val = <?php echo trim(file_get_contents("/var/www/html/ht41.txt")); ?>;
data_val2 = 30.8;
```

Note that the safest way to pass values from php to javascript, is to use `json_encode()` but as you have mentioned that your file contains only `23.54` I have not done that here. Using `json_encode()` will ensure that the variables you pass to javascript will be properly escaped / encoded and quoted.

Comment: Nice explanation :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Work, but not refresh data every x second.... can you help me ?